# Loop through nested SCSS list using key/value

Tags: css, sass, each, scss-mixins

I have a nested `scss` list with some font definitions:

```
$font-cinzel: "Cinzel", serif;
$font-poppins: "Poppins", sans-serif;

$fonts: (
    "title": (
        "all": (
            font-family: $font-cinzel
        ),
        "sm": (
            font-size: 26px,
      line-height: 1.4
        ),
        "lg": (
            font-size: 80px,
      line-height: 1.6
        )
    ),
    "text": (
        "all": (
            font-family: $font-poppins
        ),
        "sm": (
            font-size: 16px,
      line-height: 1.2
        ),
        "lg": (
            font-size: 36px,
      line-height: 1.4
        )
    )
);
```

Now I would like to write a `mixin` and a `function` to generate a styling block when passing the font name for each viewport. So all styles defined in `all` should be rendered outside of a `media query` (rule for all viewports to avoid redundancy). All other style which are unique for the viewport are defined in the viewport block e.g. all small styles are in `sm`, all large styles with different values in `lg` etc. I also have a breakpoint mixin, where I map the `min-width` by using the viewport name form the font list:

**breakpoint mixin:**

```
$breakpoints: (
    sm: 768px,
    md: 1024px,
    lg: 1280px,
    xl: 1400px
);

@function get-bp($bp) {
    @if $bp {
        $bp: map-get($breakpoints, $bp);
    } @else {
        @error "Parameter #{$vp} is unknown or empty.";
    }

    @return $bp;
}
```

**This is how I try to loop the stuff:**

```
@function get-value($definition, $vp) {
    @each $prop, $val in map-get($definition, $vp) {
        @return $val;
    }
}

@mixin font($name) {
    $definition: map-get($fonts, $name);

    @each $key, $value in $definition {
        @if $key == "all" {
            $prop: get-value($definition, $key);
        } @else {
            @media (min-width: get-bp($key)) {
                $prop: get-value($definition, $key);
            }
        }
    }
}

h1 {
  @include font('title');
}

p {
  @include font('text');
}
```

Expected output:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the styles are not available for the elements.

**Here is the codepen:** https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/QWdOZPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your update in your question:
**Here is a mixin example to your updated requirements.**

The example is done in a more general way for multiple use and a good readability.

So font-sizing-settings works as well as margins or even (nearly) every other property setting you would like ot adapt to the breakpoints. And once more with map-element `selector` it works on simple elements (tags), on classes, id's and more complex selectors as well.

Additional to the `$rules` map it is based on a breakpoint map. That make sure it works on all breakpoints adviced to the project. But rules to the breakpoints are only added to an element if noted in the rule map ... so you can say: it's an universal swiss knife.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
//###### SASS
// this example assumes:
// breakpoints allways min-width ...
$breakpoints: (
    sm: 768px,
    md: 1024px,
    lg: 1280px,
    xl: 1400px
);

$rules: (

    title: (

        selector: 'h1',

        all: (
            font-family: 'Arial',
            font-size: 26px,
            line-height: 1.4,
        ),

        sm: (
            font-size: 26px,
            line-height: 1.4,
        ),
        lg: (
            font-size: 80px,
            line-height: 1.6,
        ),
        xl: (
            font-size: 100px,
        ),
    ),

    text: (

        selector: 'p',

        all: (
            font-family: 'Courier New',
            font-size: 26px,
            line-height: 1.4,
        ),

        sm: (
            font-size: 16px,
            line-height: 1.2,
        ),
        lg: (
            font-size: 36px,
            line-height: 1.4,
        )
    ),

) !default;



@mixin fontSizing($rule-map, $breakpoints: $breakpoints){


    @each $element, $settings-map in $rule-map {

        $selector: map-get($settings-map, selector);

        // write generel rules
        #{$selector} {      
            @each $property, $value in map-get($settings-map, all){
                #{$property}: $value;
            }
        }

        // rules for every breakpoint
        @each $breakpoint, $breakpoint-setting in $breakpoints {

            // only if breakpoint values set for element
            @if map-has-key( $settings-map, $breakpoint ){

                // write breakpoints rule
                @media ( min-width: #{$breakpoint-setting} ){
                    #{$selector} {
                        @each $property, $value in map-get($settings-map, $breakpoint){
                            #{$property}: $value;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }//if

        }//each

    }//each

}//mixin


//##### CALL MIXIN
@include fontSizing($rules);


//##### COMPILES TO...

h1 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
}
p {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  p {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}
```

---

**ADDITIONAL HINT/IMPULSE:**
It is possible to compress the rule map. In that case the code working is less, - but more specialised to single tags only and the pre-defined font-sizing settings ... and it is less readable. The general construction of the mixin would be the same but code writing would change a little bit as you work with predefined properties and nested lists instead of nested maps. Feel free to adapt the code. Here is an example for the possible compression to the rule-map:

```
$rule: (
    h1: (
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        all: (10px, 1.2),
        sm: (12px, 1.4),
        lg: (24px, 1.6),
    ),
    p: (
        fontFamily: 'Courier New',
        all: (8px, 1.2),
        sm: (10px, 1.4),
        lg: (20px, 1.6),
        xl: (24px, 1.8),
    ),
) !default;
```

Comment: So your hint with `#{$prop}` was enough to solve my pen - thanks for that! Here is my solution: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/QWdOZPN

Answer (score 1):

There are some huddles in your code ...

1. The mixin uses an  `@each` loop ... which is not needed but malicious as you don't want to write all classes at once but to use it to include only a special group of properties to a single class/selector (in your example you try to advice to `h1 {...}` only.
2. The error:

- In your loop the mixins calls every element in `map-get($fonts, $name)' which in your example is inner map` title`.
- Now for every element of this map (`= fontFamily, sm, lg`) it should do something ...
- In your case you assume all elements are maps to get a value from it.
- So the loop takes the first element `fontFamily`
- There you try to get the value for a inner element `fontFamily` ...
- SASS first checks the funciton `map-get` and realize `fontFamily` you named as map for the function is not a map ...
- At that point SASS and ends ...

... and you are in trouble.

**What you may do:**

1. Reorganize your map. You can do it easier: only store the values.
2. In your mixin call direct the value you need. No loop necessary! You only need two special values which you can call targeted.
3. And don't forget to advice a line height which fits your new font-size ;-)

Code could look like this:

```
// ### SASS

$fonts: (
    title: (
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        sm: 12px,
        lg: 24px,
    ),
    text: (
        fontFamily: 'Courier New',
        sm: 10px,
        lg: 20px,
    ),
) !default;

@mixin font( $item, $size  ) {
    font-family: map-get(map-get($fonts, $item), fontFamily );
    font-size: map-get(map-get($fonts, $item), $size );
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

h1 {
    @include font( title, sm);
}



// ### Compiles to CSS

h1 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks quite good but it does not really solve my case. Maybe I didn't explained it to the end since I tried to make the easiest snippet to understand, but my overall idea is to load font-styles for an element for each viewport. Is there a way to go to a private chat channel in stackoverflow so I could show you the whole sass file? Cheers.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. So 'sm' and 'lg' are the breakpoints? You can adapt the mixin to achieve that. Should the mixin be used to single elements? You can write the whole rule including `@media` variations with the mixin and advice the values as shown in the example ... but indeed it is confusing ... Chat: actual I am busy and not sure if there is time today. But if you update your question with the wanted logic... I'll try to do it later (not quite sure about time) ... or others here I am sure will help ... here is a really big power of coders :-)

Comment: I'll try to explain it here: So in my design, I have font-styles for specific elements e.g. title for multiple viewports. I try to store this styles in a nested list. `all` should be rendered outside of a media-query so there will be all styles for all viewports. And variations like font-sizes, line-heights etc. should be stored in the viewport-name e.g. all styles for sm are in `sm` and the styles for lg in `lg` etc. Than I loop through this nested list and try to build a style block for each definition directly in one selector: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/QWdOZPN

Comment: PS: I've updated the question below. Thanks